# Manjaro broke after update: modules.devname not found

Tags: manjaro

My manjaro install broke after an update.
I managed to manjaro-chroot the mounted linux partition from a live boot.
And i saw a weird thing: i somehow have 2 linux versions: pacman -Q linux says linux316 3.16.57-1 and uname -r says 4.14.52-1-MANJARO.
I tried many things, but none seem to work.
My grub is fine, seeing both of the versions, but booting on linux414 give me: lib/modules/[VERSION]/modules.devname not found error that leads to hibernation device [UUID=] not found and booting on linux316 give me: failed to load start kernel modules.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your live boot (**/dev/sdXY** is where your broken Manjaro installed):

```
# mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
# mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev

# cp /etc/hosts /mnt/etc
# cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc
# chroot /mnt rm /etc/mtab 2> /dev/null
# chroot /mnt ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab

# chroot /mnt
```

Okay, now you are in the environment of your broken Manjaro, try to run the upgrade command again:

```
# pacman -Syu
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, but i reinstalled a more stable version of manjaro. I know how it broke and i wont do the same mistake again, but yes what you say might work as a fix !